# Нажатие на картинку

Tags: html

Глупый наверное вопрос, но я понял как делать так чтобы при нажатии картинка заменялась на другую картинку, а как сделать так чтобы при повторном нажатии возвращалась первоначальная?
Вот код сейчас:

```
<img src="images/Male.jpg" onclick=this.src="images/Age.jpg" >
```

Comment: В функции обрабатывающей клик по картинке сравнивать src. В зависимости от того какой текущий менять на второй.

Answer (score 4):

```
<img 
    src="images/Male.jpg" 
    onclick="this.src='images/'+(this.src=='images/Male.jpg'?'Age.jpg':'Male.jpg')"
>
```

хм